# How to deploy frontend and node.js server on same VPS and domain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, vps

My task is create landing page which sends emails with requisites for payment on submitting form.
So I have simple static frontend (index.html, css/, js/, img/) and express server which sends emails (server.js);
On my localhost I run the frontend on `localhost:3000` and server.js on `localhsot:3000`. After adding CORS headers everything started work fine, emails were successfully sent.

For production I've bought a VPS with ubuntu to deploy all this.
I've setup nginx so my frontend available on myDomainName.com. But when I run server.js it doesn't receive requests as it did on dev server. In the same time if I connect via ssh and type `curl myDomainName.com:3000/`, I receive response 'Hi';

```
// server.js
// some code...
app.get('/' function (req, res) { res.status(200).end('Hi'); }
app.listen(3000, function () { console.log('Server listening on port 3000!'); })


// frontendFormHandler.js
// some code...
$.get('myDomainName.com:3000/', function(data){ console.log(data) })
```

How should I set up all this to make it work on same VPS, same domain, but on different ports?
What is the right way to deploy those kind of small projects? Should I choose another instruments?

Comment: Are you sure your Firewall allows outside connections on port 3000? Most standard configs don't allow this

Comment: That's it! Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most UNIX systems the firewall is configured to only allow traffic from other clients on ports `80` and `443` for HTTP and HTTPS, all other ports are blocked for security reasons.

To allow the ports (with ufw) use

```
$ (sudo) ufw allow 3000/tcp
$ (sudo) ufw allow 3000/udp
```

Or, for IPTables:

```
$ (sudo) iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
$ (sudo) iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

to allow connections on TCP or UDP